# Publish RDS server azure application proxy (error)

Tags: proxy, azure, rds

I am trying to publish the RDS server through azure application proxy, by following the steps in this guide.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-proxy-publish-remote-desktop#direct-rds-traffic-to-application-proxy

In my environment I am using split DNS and I have successfully achieved to publish the RDweb application using a custom domain. But when I try to connect using internet explorer I am getting the following error.

> “Your computer can’t connect to the remote computer because the Remote
>   Destop Gateway server is temporally unavailable. Try reconnecting
>   later or contact your network administrator for assistance.”

Comment: Unfortunately, that error is pretty generic and could be for a number of reasons. A few things to check, have you published the RDS app proxy app using pass through and not pre-auth? Have you ensured that the internal URL you are using for the gateway is reachable on your network? Is there any information in teh app proxy connector event log?

Comment: Hi sorry for the generic question, but I wasn't even aware of what was the problem :). I have already published using preauthentication  and some of the problems that I solve was to change the RDS FQDN using this script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Change-published-FQDN-for-2a029b80, also I needed to use internet explorer with the rds activex addon enabled